# Spring batch : FlatFileItemWriter header never called

Tags: spring-batch

I have a weird issue with my FlatFileItemWriter callbacks.
I have a custom ItemWriter implementing both FlatFileFooterCallback and FlatFileHeaderCallback. Consequently, I set header and footer callbacks in my FlatFileItemWriter like this :

**ItemWriter Bean**

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemWriter<CityItem> writer(FlatFileItemWriter<CityProcessed> flatWriter, @Value("#{jobExecutionContext[inputFile]}") String inputFile) {
        CityItemWriter itemWriter = new CityItemWriter();
        flatWriter.setHeaderCallback(itemWriter);
        flatWriter.setFooterCallback(itemWriter);
        itemWriter.setDelegate(flatWriter);
        itemWriter.setInputFileName(inputFile);
        return itemWriter;
}
```

**FlatFileItemWriter Bean**

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<CityProcessed> flatFileWriterArchive(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext[outputFileArchive]}") String outputFile) {
    FlatFileItemWriter<CityProcessed> flatWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<CityProcessed>();
    FileSystemResource isr;
    isr = new FileSystemResource(new File(outputFile));
    flatWriter.setResource(isr);
    DelimitedLineAggregator<CityProcessed> aggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<CityProcessed>();
    aggregator.setDelimiter(";");
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<CityProcessed> beanWrapper = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<CityProcessed>();
    beanWrapper.setNames(new String[]{
        "country", "name", "population", "popUnder25", "pop25To50", "pop50to75", "popMoreThan75"
    });
    aggregator.setFieldExtractor(beanWrapper);
    flatWriter.setLineAggregator(aggregator);
    flatWriter.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    return flatWriter;
}
```

**Step Bean**

```
@Bean
public Step stepImport(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<CityFile> reader, ItemWriter<CityItem> writer, ItemProcessor<CityFile, CityItem> processor,
    @Qualifier("flatFileWriterArchive") FlatFileItemWriter<CityProcessed> flatFileWriterArchive, ExecutionContextPromotionListener executionContextListener) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepImport").<CityFile, CityItem> chunk(10).reader(reader(null)).processor(processor).writer(writer).stream(flatFileWriterArchive)
        .listener(executionContextListener).build();
}
```

I have the classic content in my writeFooter, writeHeader and write methods.

**ItemWriter code**

```
public class CityItemWriter implements ItemWriter<CityItem>, FlatFileFooterCallback, FlatFileHeaderCallback, ItemStream {
    private FlatFileItemWriter<CityProcessed> writer;
    private static int totalUnknown = 0;
    private static int totalSup10000 = 0;
    private static int totalInf10000 = 0;
    private String inputFileName = "-";

    public void setDelegate(FlatFileItemWriter<CityProcessed> delegate) {
        writer = delegate;
    }

    public void setInputFileName(String name) {
        inputFileName = name;
    }

    private Predicate<String> isNullValue() {
        return p -> p == null;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends CityItem> cities) throws Exception {
        List<CityProcessed> citiesCSV = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CityItem item : cities) {
             String populationAsString = "";
             String less25AsString = "";
             String more25AsString = "";
            /*
             * Some processing to get total Unknown/Sup 10000/Inf 10000
             * and other data
             */
            // Write in CSV file
            CityProcessed cre = new CityProcessed();
            cre.setCountry(item.getCountry());
            cre.setName(item.getName());
            cre.setPopulation(populationAsString);
            cre.setLess25(less25AsString);
            cre.setMore25(more25AsString);
            citiesCSV.add(cre);
        }
        writer.write(citiesCSV);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeFooter(Writer fileWriter) throws IOException {
        String newLine = "\r\n";
        String totalUnknown= "Subtotal:;Unknown;" + String.valueOf(nbUnknown) + newLine;
        String totalSup10000 = ";Sum Sup 10000;" + String.valueOf(nbSup10000) + newLine;
        String totalInf10000 = ";Sum Inf 10000;" + String.valueOf(nbInf10000) + newLine;
        String total = "Total:;;" + String.valueOf(nbSup10000 + nbInf10000 + nbUnknown) + newLine;
        fileWriter.write(newLine);
        fileWriter.write(totalUnknown);
        fileWriter.write(totalSup10000);
        fileWriter.write(totalInf10000);
        fileWriter.write(total );
    }

    @Override
    public void writeHeader(Writer fileWriter) throws IOException {
        String newLine = "\r\n";
        String firstLine= "FILE PROCESSED ON: ;" + new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new Date()) + newLine;
        String secondLine= "Filename: ;" + inputFileName + newLine;
        String colNames= "Country;Name;Population...;...having less than 25;...having more than 25";
        fileWriter.write(firstLine);
        fileWriter.write(secondLine);
        fileWriter.write(newLine);
        fileWriter.write(colNames);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        writer.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext context) throws ItemStreamException {
        writer.open(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext context) throws ItemStreamException {
        writer.update(context);
    }
}
```

When I run my batch, I only have the data for each city (write method part) and the footer lines. If I comment the whole content of write method and footer callback, I still don't have the header lines. I tried to add a System.out.println() text in my header callback, it looks like it's never called.

Here is an example of the CSV file produced by my batch :

```
France;Paris;2240621;Unknown;Unknown
France;Toulouse;439553;Unknown;Unknown
Spain;Barcelona;1620943;Unknown;Unknown
Spain;Madrid;3207247;Unknown;Unknown
[...]
Subtotal:;Unknown;2
;Sum Sup 10000;81
;Sum Inf 10000;17
Total:;;100
```

What is weird is that my header used to work before, when I added both footer and header callbacks. I didn't change them, and I don't see what I've done in my code to "broke" my header callback... And of course, I have no save of my first code. Because I see only now that my header has disappeared (I checked my few last files, and it looks like my header is missing for some time but I didn't see it), I can't just remove my modifications to see when/why it happens.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing obvious sticks out.  Can you provide a full example that illustrates the issue?

Comment: Could you post your CityItemWriter code. It seems to be a java.io.writer and a SpringBatch Item writer ... kind of confusing. More code might help

Comment: I added the ItemWriter code. I'll need to insert some data into a database (and produce a CSV file at the same time), that's why I use my own ItemWriter which uses a FlatFileItemWriter as a delegate. I hope it's clearer with the code

Comment: @MichaelMinella : I'm not sure to understand what you're expected by "a full example that illustrates the issue", but I added a CSV file produced by my batch. I just removed some cities in the middle of the file.

Comment: Have you debugged what is happening when open is being called?

Comment: please add your complete job config/implementation, especially the flatwriter part - is the flatwriter stepScoped as well? i ask because you tangle 2 writers in a rather strange way

Comment: @MichaelMinella : I set breakpoints on  `open()`, `writeHeader()` and `writeFooter()`, and my debugger stopped only on the footer breakpoint...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Java config as you are, it's best to return the most specific type possible (the opposite of what you're normally told to do in java programming).  In this case, your writer is returning `ItemWriter`, but is step scoped.  Because of this a proxy is created that can only see the type that your java config returns which in this case is `ItemWriter` and does not expose the methods on the `ItemStream` interface.  If you return `CityItemWriter`, I'd expect things to work.