# Adding @JobScope on an ItemReader makes it fail

Tags: spring-batch

I have an issue with the @JobScope annotation.
I'm using spring-batch, with spring-boot, so no xml. I'm also using hibernate, and wish to use it in my readers.

Here is my item reader :

```
@Bean(name = "readerFactures")
public ItemReader<XFctFacture> readerFactures(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateCursorItemReader itemReader = new HibernateCursorItemReader();
    itemReader.setQueryString("from XFctFacture where typeFacture=1 and statut=1");
    itemReader.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

    return itemReader;
}
```

And everythink works fine, so far ... :)

But now I want to access to a parameter from my job, so I need to annotate my reader with the @JobScope.
So my new code is :

```
@Bean(name = "readerFactures")
@JobScope
public ItemReader<XFctFacture> readerFactures(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    HibernateCursorItemReader itemReader = new HibernateCursorItemReader();
    itemReader.setQueryString("from XFctFacture where typeFacture=1 and statut=1");
    itemReader.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

    return itemReader;
}
```

And with this, when I execute the job, I have the following exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader.doRead(HibernateCursorItemReader.java:155) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:88) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
```

The cursor is null, it appears that my ItemReader had never been opened.

Any clues ?

Thanks

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365219/spring-batch-flatfileitemwriter-header-never-called/29517409#29517409  In short, you're returning `ItemReader` which means your stream isn't being auto-registered.  Return `HibernateCursorItemReader` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick ! I just have now an exception when the job ends (which I hadn't before adding the @StepScope) :  [WARN] com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ConnectionProxy - Connection (1229786690) wrapping ClosedConnection (HikariPool-0) marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(17009).
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Instruction fermÃ©e

Comment: Looks like some connection are not closed correctly ...

Comment: Can you open another question and include the appropriate configuration and stack trace for it?